# Determine if the following extensions are normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

I wish to determine if the extension

1) $L = Q(e^{2πi/n})$ is normal over $Q$,

2) $K(a)$ is normal over $F_3(t)$ where $a$ is root in a splitting field of $x^3-t$

For 1) Is it like polynomial $x^n-1$ splits completely in $Q(e^{2πi/n})$?

For 2)  Is the idea like $K(a)$ is an extension of degree 3 over $Q$ but if it is normal then it contains all roots of the polynomial which leads to a  contradiction of the degree?

Comment: Comments 1) That is correct. Show that $x^n-1$ splits over that field, but does not split over any proper subfield. 2) This is a trick question. It is essential that we are in characteristic three. The answer would be different if you were asked about $L(a)$, $a^3=t$, with $L=F_5(t)$. Hint: what's $(x-a)^3$ in $K(a)[x]$?

Comment: In 1) How to show it does not split over any proper subfield? and in 2) You are saying so the extension is normal because $(x-a)^3=x^3-a$ in $K(a)[x]$ ? Don't really get it though~

Comment: 1) That's the easy part. One of the zeros of $x^n-1$ generates $L$, so no smaller extension will do. 2) You just showed that $x^3-a^3$ splits over $K(a)$.

Comment: 1) So can I just say the roots of the polynomial $x^n-1$ in $Q[x]$are $e^{2πi/n}$ (How about ± case ?) so this polynomial splits completely in $Q(e^{2πi/n})$ ?

Comment: To be precise, the roots are $e^{2kπi/n}$ right so how to show splits completely in $Q(e^{2πi/n})$ hmm